# Operator to return value only if truthy in JavaScript or TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

This comes up a lot in React components but say I have something like this:

```
<Carousel interval={modalOpen ? null : 8000}>
```

I wish I could just do (this obviously wont work):

```
<Carousel interval={modalOpen ? 8000}>
```

In TypeScript I know about `??` but that provides a fallback which I don't want. I basically want the inverse of that. If a value is truthy (in this example `modalOpen`) I want it to return a value (`8000` here) if not just return undefined as if modalOpen had no return value.

I'm pretty sure nothing exists in TypeScript or vanilla JS but wanted to check if I was overlooking something or if there's a better practice then having to have a ternary with undefined/null all over.

Comment: Does it need to return `undefined`? Or will the falsy value of `modalOpen` suffice?

Comment: `!modalOpen && 8000` might work if a falsy value is treated as nothing.

Comment: Yeah, `modalOpen ? 8000` indeed sounds like `modalOpen && 8000` is what you need. It'll not be null but false if `modalOpen` is falsey, but that's fine with React afaik. This is basically conditional rendering of an attribute instead of a component.

Comment: If you need a particular falsy value like `null`, then `!modalOpen && 8000 || null` will do it (as long as whatever takes the place of `8800` is truthy), but as soon as you care about the exact value for both true and false, you really want `modalOpen ? null : 8000`

Comment: @ChrisG "_It'll not be null but false_" It will return the value of `modalOpen` when it is falsy. Not necessarily `false`.

Comment: @Ivar True, it basically depends on the attribute. Can it be falsey or not, and what happens if it is. It works fine for `hidden` for instance, not for `style`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<Carousel interval={!modalOpen && 8000} />